# why does it will show scrollbar only in ie11?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

the example is http://fiddle.jshell.net/dxcqcv/s8atrxdt/

I already test it in ie11, firefox and chrome, and only ie11 will show scrollbar

and I know just set 'overflow:hidden;' to parent div, the scrollbar will hidden.

but I wanna know why ie11 will show scrollbar and sometime I wanna show scrollbar for contents over windows.thx.

Comment: what's the version of your IE?

Comment: @DyrandzFamador ie11